# Django multiple embedded foreign keys on Admin page?

Tags: python, django

How do you display multiple foreign keys on the django admin page?

eg:

```
class Parent(model.Models):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=200)

class Child(model.Models):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = model.CharField(max_length=3)
    parent = model.ForeignKey(Parent) # assume one parent right now... 

class Toy(model.Models):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = model.ForeignKey(Child)
```

Given example, a Parent can have multiple children, a child can have one parent but multiple toys, and a toy can have one owner.

Comment: It isn't clear what your goal is. "display multiple foreign keys" could mean many different things

Comment: Are you talking about the inline form to display related foreign key objects? If it is, I think you are even referring to multi-level inline, which is will be very tricky to achieve

Comment: I think thats it... multi-level inline... I guess I need to create a new admin view?

Comment: multi-level inline is achievable, but it will mess up your form page eventually. I suggest reconsider your approach.

Comment: Change my model or change how I display it?

Comment: I thought about the example I used... I thinking a better one may be like an outline... Header, subheader, etc.